# Error converting data type nvarchar to float from table column

Tags: sql-server

I Have a table `accounts` in which column `col` is type of `nvarchar(20)`

`select  col from accounts where col='12'`

It returns

> 12

but when I query
 `select  col from accounts where cast(col as float)=12` 
It returns

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

After inserting into a temporary table , it works normally

`select  col into #tmp from accounts where col ='12'
select * from #tmp where cast(col as float)=12`

Why I get this error?

Comment: SQL Server tries to cast **all** cell values to float before comparing them, even those that have non numeric characters in it.

Comment: Because there are values in that column that cannot be cast to FLOAT. Use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) instead.

Comment: try using this statement to see value which is causing the issue  `select  col ,try_Cast(col as float) from accounts`  the offending value would be null

Comment: Thanks. I understood.